# Welded parts not appearing

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I am trying to weld parts together in KSP with the UbioWelding plugin.  The "Weld It" button appears and the in game dialog to weld parts seems to work fine, but the finished part never appears in my parts catalog.  The welded part does show up in the UbioWelding Parts directory.

Here are the plugins I am using:

[image]

Here is the version.txt from the welding plugin:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reloading the game?  KSP might not load the part into memory until the game is restarted.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that with no joy.

Comment: I also notice that it's only the part.cfg file.  Are you sure that there isn't supposed to be a model file as well?

Comment: Perhaps -- not sure.  That directory and its contents are generated by the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the welding mod is mangling the filenames of the parts being welded.  I think this is caused due to cross platform issues with Unity -- I am running on a Mac.

Specifically, welded parts have references like this:

[image]

When they should look like this:

[image]

If you go into the welded part's .cfg file and fix these errors, the welded part works fine.